# NSURLSession fails when attempting to us assigned IP instead of localhost or home

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlsession

I have a server running locally (my IP is 192.168.0.98) and have been experimenting with some networking code to access it. Originally this was done via AFNetworking, but I've now done it with a `NSURLSession` like this:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.98:8080/api"];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL: url
                                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                        NSLog(@"Body: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                    }];
[task resume];
```

I've then run it with these 3 URLs:

- `http://localhost:8080/api` -> works.
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api` -> works.
- `http://192.168.0.98:8080/api` -> fails with the error:

  ```
  Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain 
  Code=2 "No such file or directory" 
  UserInfo={
      NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.0.98:8080/api,
      NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.98:8080api,
      _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=2,
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1
  }
  ```

Where 192.168.0.98 is the IP assigned to this machine. If I run these URLs from [PAW](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) or a browser it works just fine. But from a unit test it fails.

From my project's perspective I can just use `localhost`. So this is not a deal breaker. But I'm curious as to why it's not working.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: at a guess because that host couldn't be reached or there was no process listening on port 8080 on that address

Comment: Indeed; have you tested this using `telnet` or `netcat` or something from the command line?

Comment: I've tested this use a REST client and it's fine with all the URLs. 192.168.0.98 is actually this machine. Trace route shows the same route for 192.168.0.98, localhost and 127.0.0.1. It's only AfNetworking that is having an issue with this.

Comment: maybe a router problem... since localhost and 127.0.0.1 are handled quite differently than an IP address.

Comment: Same problem here. Only fails in the iOS simulator, if I access that IP:port from any web browser and it works.

Comment: BTW it has started failing since I installed El Capitan (yesterday)

Comment: After more testing it only happens on iOS 9 and tvOS 9, not on iOS 8 simulator.

Comment: Same here, it seems a El Capitan issue

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr: Use your [Bonjour local link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/domainnames.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002460-CJBDIAHA) domain name instead of your IP address.

I just ran into this problem myself. I'm building an API locally and don't want to deploy to an external server yet, but I need to call the API from both the simulator as well as devices. I tried at first using localhost, but of course that doesn't work for devices since localhost would be the device itself, not my Mac. IP address worked for the devices, but doesn't work in the simulator. I then remembered that I can use the `.local` domain name for my Mac for other networking addressability, and sure enough it works. I can use `http://mymac.local/` as the base URL for my API requests on both the simulator as well as my test devices.

I'm not sure why using the actual IP address doesn't work, but this may give you an option that will work for your needs.

Comment: `sudo scutil --get LocalHostName` will give your local name to use in the url: http://`localHostName`.local/