# Swift URLSession not working for localhost calls

Tags: swift, rest, urlsession

I'm writing a basic API call in Swift using URLRequests, and for whatever reason my call is never executed. I have multiple calls to an external server API using the same method and the functionality is just as expected, however, for my server running locally I get no response or even behavior within the dataTask closure.

I have tried any relevant solutions I could find online such as: [Swift URL Session and URL Request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705278/swift-url-session-and-url-request-not-working) and [Swift 3, URLSession dataTask completionHandler not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053593/swift-3-urlsession-datatask-completionhandler-not-called/39055093). But none of these solutions seem to fix my issue. I know that the local API is working as any calls through Postman go through without fail, yet even after using the Swift snippet provided by Postman, I get no functionality.

```
func doFoo(id: String, completion: @escaping ([[Float]]) -> ()) {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "127.0.0.1:8080/doFoo/\(id)")!, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    print("THIS IS REACHED")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        print("THIS IS NEVER REACHED")
        guard let data = data else {
            self.semaphore.signal()
            return
        }
        do {
            // Decode json using JSONDecoder
            // Call completion with JSON data
        } catch {
             print(error)
        }
        self.semaphore.signal()
    }
    task.resume()
    self.semaphore.wait()
}
```

Other posts suggest that this could be an issue with the thread or execution completing before the closure is executed; while I am not super familiar with how the request executes and the behavior of semaphores, my understanding is that they are a way to request threads and prevent the above from happening.

If anyone more familiar with these topics could help me identify and understand why this issue is occurring, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to set ```http://localhost:8080/doFoo/\(id)```

Comment: This is what I had originally, and unfortunately it does not work either. I saw a post that said perhaps you need the actual address (127.0.0.1) so I swapped it. Unfortunately, neither of these seem to work. @RajaKishan

Comment: did you have the actual scheme before? Be sure to include the `http://` portion

Comment: Check this answere : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585140/14733292

Comment: As you have a completion handler what's the semaphore for? Don't force an asynchronous pattern to become synchronous. And – as mentioned – a valid (remote) URL must start with a scheme

Comment: By setting up the bonjour link, I have managed to somewhat resolve the issue. It appears the API calls go through, but I still do not see any of the relevant print statements nor is the completion being called.I seem to get a new error that is rather long, but the key information seems to be `nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler ... unregistered notification for write_timeout failed`. I'm unsure if this is valuable or if it arises from a different issue. @RajaKishan

Comment: Truthfully, I do not fully understand semaphores. The only thread safety strategies that I am familiar with are Mutex Locks and I am still trying to understand the purpose of semaphores. While I understand them at a basic level, I don't quite see their benefit in these API calls and just trust that the internet knows more than me. Does a completion serve a similar purpose? It seems to me that a semaphore is for thread safety and a completion is just when I wish to perform work once the task finishes. @vadian

Comment: A semaphore is pointless if you have an asynchronous completion handler and is bad practice anyway.

Comment: I can assure you that localhost URLs do work in general.

Comment: So best practice would be to just completely remove all the semaphores? @vadian

Comment: In your case, yes.

Comment: @vadian Sorry for my delayed response. By removing the semaphores, this completely solved the issue. I noticed that non-localhost functions broke when I removed the semaphores though. They all still have completions, could you explain why this might happen? Additionally, if you wish to write a slight answer regarding semaphores, I can mark it as correct as that did solve the issue.

Comment: `dataTask` works reliably without semaphores. Probably there is something wrong with the URL.

Comment: Calls all seem to be working fine, it seems like without semaphores blocking no longer occurs and so calls complete out of order - so while I might use one call to get a session ID, another call requiring that ID won't have it at the time of execution. @vadian

Comment: Due to the asynchronous behavior you have to call the second task in the closure of the first one or in the custom completion handler.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand now. Thank you so much for the help! @vadian